# I cannot view my data that is stored in $_GET

Tags: php

Ok so I have this

```
<a href="vehpage.php?getVar=<?php echo $search_rs['trucknum']; ?>"
```

Now when someone clicks that the get variable is set as the number they searched.

I already check and my get variable is set.

I did

```
print_r($_GET);
```

and it showed me that my variable was in fact there.

Now Im trying to show it on the same page but not as a print as a echo.

i did

```
echo $_GET['trucknum'];
```

when I do that I get an error that says undefined value trucknum.

Comment: show your print_r($_GET); result

Comment: Hope you are accessing a page like yourscript.php?trucknum=1234

Comment: No you are getting the wrong variable name. Try `echo $_GET['getVar'];`

Comment: My PRint_R result is

Comment: Array ( [getVar] => 2053 )

Comment: acn you show us the link that opens that page or how do you send the GET request ?

Comment: But how do I show other data that is used in conjunction with that getVar... Like that part is only the truck num.. I also want to show the vin and other stuff that is associated with that trucknum

Comment: You have to send the vin number and model the same way you did with getVar (trucknum) like: `vehpage.php?getVar=<?php echo $search_rs['trucknum']; ?>&vin=<?php //YOUR_VIN_NO ?>&model=<?php //YOUR_MODEL ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
echo $_GET['trucknum'];
```

TO

```
 echo $_GET['getVar'];
```

For the other part of your question:

```
<a href="vehpage.php?getVar=<?php echo $search_rs['trucknum']; ?>&vin=<?php //YOUR_VIN_NO ?>&model=<?php //YOUR_MODEL ?>">Link</a>
```

Then you can access them as:

```
 echo $_GET['getVar'];
 echo $_GET['vin'];
 echo $_GET['model'];
```

Comment: Exactly! Your awesome!

Comment: I tried what you said, But now it says undefined index vin

Comment: Nevermind, I was doing it wrong! Thanks a lot it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't any `trucknum` in `GET` array try with `getVar`

```
echo $_GET['getVar'];
```

if you want to show trucknum in page then you need to send in query string like

```
yoururl?getVar=fhgh&trucknum=2035
```

then you will get

```
echo $_GET['trucknum'];
```

Comment: your welcome :) you can accept/upvote helpful answers